# Error message from filter array

Tags: workflow, azure-logic-apps

So I have tried to get the error message from a filter array in a logic app workflow, this is what i have tried:

```
@body('Filter_array')['error']

@actions('Filter_array')['outputs']['body']['error']
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

It says: "cannot be evaluated because property 'error' cannot be selected. ".

But i can clearly see the "error" in the body object in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i managed to figure it out, i missed the fact that the array doesnt give me a single object as i thought i set it up to. so the solution was this:

```
@string(actions('Filter_array')['outputs']['body'][0]['error'])
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with @actions('Filter_array')['error'] ?

You have to distinguish 2 types of errors.

First error can occur during execution of your connector. Eg. The filter did not match. In this case, the connector executed and returns an output with an error-message.

Second error is a runtime error that can occur on the connector. For example if the input of your connector is invalid and the executing of the connector can't be triggered. In this case, the connector does not generate an output or result. In that case, you have to catch the exception with @actions('Filter_array')['error']

Comment: Hey @StevenVanEycken, thank you for your fast response, it didnt work.